# How to display Account Name in a lookup field on Tasks? When task was created on a case

Tags: process-builder, lookup, account, tasks, activity

I have a custom lookup field called 'Account Name' on Task where I use a process builder to set its value to **[Task].Accountid**.

This field is populated with Account name if **Related To** field of Task is Account or Opportunity but not for Cases. Its blank when Related To is a case.

**AccountId and Account.Name are blank for Tasks that have Related To - Case**

Any idea how to populate Account Name on Tasks when Task is related To case?